# React Beautiful dnd converting functional componentings

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm trying to convert beautiful-dnd to functional components and split them into different components but I'm just wondering why this is throwing an error?

[image: Edit react-beautiful-dnd tutorial]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue in `task.js`. You forgot to spread the `provided.dragHandleProps`

```
import React from 'react'
import { Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd'

const Task = props => {
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <Draggable draggableId={props.task.id} index={props.index}>
      {(provided, snapshot) => (
        <div
          ref={provided.innerRef} // <-- this as well
          {...provided.draggableProps}
          {...provided.dragHandleProps} // <-- here
        >
          {props.task.content}
        </div>
      )}
    </Draggable>
  )
}

export default Task
```

Comment: Not sure if that was needed but there is still a cross-origin error

Comment: @Freddy. change `innerRef` to `ref` in column.js as like in task.js of this answer

Comment: Ah I see the issue was with the support of innerRef